# Update TableA from TableB Match

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've got two tables, the first column match on both tables and I need to `UPDATE` TableA with all the data from TableB, ONLY where `TableA.Column1` and `TableB.Column1` match. I'm having a really hard time wrapping my head around how to get this to work... TableA has about 80+ columns and TableB has around 100+. I'm attempting this in Microsoft Access.

**TableA**

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | ....... | ColumnX |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1    |  DataA  |         |  DataA  | ....... |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    2    |  DataA  |         |  DataA  | ....... |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    3    |  DataA  |         |  DataA  | ....... |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    4    |  DataA  |         |  DataA  | ....... |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    X    |  DataA  |         |  DataA  | ....... |         |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**TableB**

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | ....... | ColumnX |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1    |         |  DataB  |         | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    2    |         |  DataB  |         | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    3    |         |  DataB  |         | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    4    |         |  DataB  |         | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    X    |         |  DataB  |         | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**End Result of TableA**

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | ....... | ColumnX |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    1    |  DataA  |  DataB  |  DataA  | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    2    |  DataA  |  DataB  |  DataA  | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    3    |  DataA  |  DataB  |  DataA  | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    4    |  DataA  |  DataB  |  DataA  | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... | ....... |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|    X    |  DataA  |  DataB  |  DataA  | ....... |  DataB  |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

**What I've Tried so far...**

`UNION` which I quickly gave up on... It seems as that was only giving me a query, where as I need to actually `UPDATE` TableA with ALL the data from TableB

And also...

```
UPDATE TableA ([Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4], ....... [ColumnX])
SELECT [Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4], ....... [ColumnX]
  FROM TableB
 WHERE (TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column2)
```

**EDIT 1:**

Tried this...

> Run-time error '3144': Syntax error in UPDATE statement

```
SQL = "   UPDATE tbleVendorData AS A " & _
      "     JOIN tbleOLD AS B " & _
      "       ON A.[Column1] = B.[Column1] " & _
      "      SET A.[Column14] = CONCAT(A.[Column14], B.[Column5])"
```

**EDIT 2:**

[image]

Comment: What's the error message? It should say approx  where the error lies.

Comment: Oh, it might be you need to do A.[Column14] + B.[Column5] rather than CONCAT. I'm a native MySQL speaker!

Comment: Changed it from `SET A.[Column14] = CONCAT(A.[Column14], B.[Column5])` to `SET A.[Column14] = (A.[Column14] + B.[Column5])` and I'm still getting the same Syntax error

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the horrible MSSQL syntax.

Comment: Try taking out the CONCAT, I think MSSQL only has the + operator. See my updated answer. Ooops, I'd left it in! Sorry. Updated it now. I'm too old for multi-tasking.

Comment: Nah still getting the same issue... tried `SET A.[EDIContact] = A.[EDIContact] + B.[EDI_Contact_Name]` and `SET A.[EDIContact] = A.[EDIContact] & B.[EDI_Contact_Name]`

Comment: Try pasting the whole query into the workbench and see if it is anymore helpful with showing exactly where the syntax error is. I've looked at the manual and it should work.

Comment: Managed to come up with a different method, I added me answer as well and it seems to work... Unfortunately it's gonna take a long time to write out all 100+ columns, but it'll do I guess. Appreciate you're attempted help thought! I still learned a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately none of these suggestions work... However after doing some deep digging the below worked for me!

```
UPDATE TableA, TableB
   SET TableA.Column15= [TableB].[Column3]
 WHERE (([TableA].[Column1]=[TableB].[Column1]));
```

Comment: This method is same as my method. The difference here is that you're using old method to join 2 tables (using comma operator and you shouldn't use that) while I've used the new method to join tables with `inner join....on` clause. Both will give the same result that's for sure..

Comment: Gotcha, well it seemed to work fine for what I need, I appreciate your suggestion too! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Following query may work:

```
UPDATE TableA 
INNER JOIN TableB 
 ON(TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column2)
SET 
    TableA.Column3 = TableB.column3,
    ...
    TableA.Columnx = TableB.columnx
Where TableA.Column1 = TableB.column1;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your answer will overwrite values in TableA with values from TableB, which isn't what the question asks for.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what this line is saying `ON(table1.Column1 = table2.Column2)`. Wouldn't this mean that table1.Column1 is trying to match with table2.Column2? That's not what is that matching values though

Comment: `ON` clause tells based on what values both tables should joined. Also, you can add the columns you want to update in `SET` clause.

Comment: Then what does means `matching values`?

Comment: The value's I'm trying to match are `TableA.Column1` and `TableB.Column1`; once they match all rows from TableA will be filled in from TableB

Comment: Instead of TableA & TableB, I used Table1 and Table2. That's why you seems confused. Am i right?

Comment: No, that's not it at all... I'm just understanding why it's `ON(TableA.Column1 = TableB.Column2)` when I'm not trying to compare those in any way what so ever... Also, I feel like Column2 is being skipped somewhere

Comment: you wrote in previous comment that you're trying to match `TableA.Column1 `and `TableB.Column1`. How can you match values without comparing? Column 2 isn't skipped. You can write the columns you want to update inside SET clause.

Answer (score 0):

Have a play with:

```
UPDATE TableA AS A JOIN TableB AS B ON A.Column1 = B.Column1 SET A.Column1 = CONCAT(A.Column1,B.Column1) ...
```

Or in MSSQL

```
UPDATE A SET A.[Column14] = A.[Column14] + B.[Column5] FROM tbleVendorData AS A JOIN tbleOLD AS B ON A.[Column1] = B.[Column1]
```

If the value for any given field is blank in one table when it isn't in the corresponding field in the second, then you could try CONCAT(A.Column1,B.Column1) for example. It's not clever, but it is easier than using IF.

Comment: It's quite sporadic on which column is blank, I should have mentioned that too sorry

Comment: So, the CONCAT solution may work quite nicely then. You won't even lose data if both fields are not blank!

Comment: Oh, I should have also mentioned that there are some columns I need to skip from TableB. Will CONCAT still work for me?

Comment: Yes, just updated my answer to show how you can do it.

Comment: Perfect, I'll give this a try and back to you! Thanks, very much appreciate it!

Comment: Hey Nick, I'm getting a Syntax error on UPDATE; I'll post what I wrote in my question above

Comment: Still getting an error here haha, I've updated my question with a picture. Tried using a `+` and `&` instead of a coma and still getting the error